# responsive background screen view

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the background when I get to a different screen size, and have it no repeat and centered

```
$(function(){
    var  moblie;
    moblie = '<section id="mobile-bk-cg"></section>';

    if ($(window).width() <= 425){
        $({'.demo-heading-wrapper').css('background-image','url(../assets/images/mobile/mobile-425-image.jpg'),
            'background-repeat':  'no-repeat', 'fixed');
    } else{
        $('.demo-heading-wrapper').css('background-image','url(../assets/images/mobile/mobile-demo-main-img-2.jpg'),
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing that In CSS, rather than doing it with Jquery

you can write your styles inside @media as below.Change width and height as per your need

```
@Media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
   background : url(<URL here>);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: <Set percentage >
}
```

The code piece is just for your reference . Your needs may be different, Please change the width and parameters as per your needs. Also edit the CSS properties as per requirements

Comment: OK cool but is their away that I can it in the code that I posted  ?

Comment: Please explore about media queries in the below link

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Also about centering an image using css, find it here

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: If you find the answer as correct, mark it as answer